# Make javaScript (not JQuery!) "activate" on keypress a CSS button:active style

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Newbie here.

I have a similar code:

```
...
<style>
.button:active {
    box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
</style>
<script>
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    // 83 is the number code for the letter "S" and 115 the for the letter "s" 
    if (e.which === 83 || e.which === 115) { 
        document.getElementById('start').click();
}
...
</script>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="start" class="button" value="Start (S)" onclick="start();">
</body>
```

If I click on the above button everything works fine, but when I press the key "S" (keycode: 115)  the function "start()" is called, but the CSS for active button doesn't start (that is, the animation for the button doesn't happen).

Question: How can I make the button:active animation start when I press "S", to make it look just as if I was clicking on the HTML button when I press the "S" key on my keyboard?

Please don't use JQuery in the answer, just plain JavaScript, since I'm not using JQuery libraries.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Good Point from @flen to use [`Element.classList.toggle();`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp) witch supported in IE >= 10

```js
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 115) { //this is the number code for the letter "S"
document.getElementById('start').click();
document.getElementById('start').classList.add("button-active");
  }
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
document.getElementById('start').classList.toggle("button-active");
}

function start() {
  console.log("start")
}
```

```html
<style>
  /*set button-active */
  .button:active,
  .button-active {
    box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
    transform: translateY(4px);
  }
</style>

<input type="button" id="start" class="button" value="Start (S)" onclick="start();" />
```

another way to do the task works for all browsers using [`Element.className`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp)

```js
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 115) { //this is the number code for the letter "S"
    document.getElementById('start').click();
    if (document.getElementById('start').className.indexOf("button-active") == -1) document.getElementById('start').className += ' button-active';
  }
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  document.getElementById('start').className = document.getElementById('start').className.replace(/button\-active/g, "");

}

function start() {
  console.log("start")
}
```

```html
<style>
  /*set button-active */
  .button:active,
  .button-active {
    box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
    transform: translateY(4px);
  }
</style>

<input type="button" id="start" class="button" value="Start (S)" onclick="start();" />
```

Comment: Excellent! For future users, you can use    `document.getElementById('start').classList.toggle("button-active");` in `document.onkeypress` if you want the HTML `button` to flicker (appear to be clicking very fast) instead of keeping it down while pressing the keyboard key

Comment: Good point @flen, but i have to say `Element.className` may be better for all browsers.

Comment: True, `className` has better compatibility. But I meant `classList.toggle` only as a means to quickly turn on and off the styling while pressing the key down on the keyboard. For just removal (like in the `document.onkeyup` bit of the code) `classList.remove()` is better (otherwise you might turn it on when pressing the key), or `classList.add()` for the `document.onkeypress`bit. BTW, thanks a lot for the answer! It was very easy to follow

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign an EventListener to the keypress. Also, you do not need to perform a click on the button, you could call the `start()`-function directly, I think?

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 115) start();
});
```

This could work for you!

EDIT: As you see in the below example, the animation is only happening, while holding down the button. The JavaScript `click()`-call is only like a very short period of holding down the button, so you wont see any animation.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("btn");
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 20px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

#btn:active {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn">
```

To get the desired effect, you could animate the element on a class. For example set it's width (or any other attribute) with the class `clicked` and toggle the class with JS.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But I don't think this will work, I do have an EventListener with "document.onkeypress". As the code is now, I agree that it would probably be best to call the <code>start</code> function directly, the problem is that it will bypass the CSS animation

Comment: Have you tried my code? Do you run the script after the DOM is fully loaded? Otherwise it will not be able to find your animated element.

Comment: This here for example (I changed `document` to `window`, but I tried both) doesn't seem to work:  `window.addEventListener("keypress", keypressHandler, false);`
`function keypressHandler(e) {`
`var keyCode = e.which;`
`  if(keyCode==115) {`
`  start();`
`  }`

Comment: Do you have some errors in the console? What are those? I think your code should work...

Comment: I tried this before. If my logic is right, what happens is this: the `button:active` style has no relation whatsoever with the javascript function `start()`. This function is simply a function, so calling it directly will have no effect on the CSS. But clicking the button with the mouse activates the button (and calls the function), and this activation will bear relation to the CSS snippet. My doubt is: how can I activate (trigger?) the CSS snippet with Javascript?

Comment: I have no console errors, I tried your code in Firefox and Iridium, in both it is not working (I also deleted every eventhandler I had in the HTML page, in order to avoid conflicts) - it doesn't even call the start function, i don't know why! (I think it has to with how the function is written directly as the parameter in addEventListener, you're calling it there and it cannot be called as parameter). The code I commented above works in calling the function though, but makes no CSS animation

Comment: I think I don't fully understand what you're saying. I changed my code according to your edit (that is, my EventListener triggers the `start` function directly, and not the `button.click()` and I made the CSS changes in your edit), but when I hit "S" the button doesn't grow larger, only when I click on it with my mouse. I think my last comment answers why. And just a heads-up: the reason your code didn't work before with keydown is because with keydown the keyCode for "S" is 83. For keypress, it's 115. I think @Mamdouh nailed the answer, but thank you for bearing with me!

Comment: Reading @Mahmoud's answer I realised he implemented what you meant with creating a new class and toggling between active and inactive classes, I now understood your answer. Thanks a lot for it!

Comment: Yep, I wanted you to do it on your own and learn while doing, instead of just give you a bunch of somehow-working code ;-)